# Set Wallpaper on application background

Tags: android, wallpaper, setting

I am making an application, in which i want to set wallpaper on application background, not on the homescreen background.
Can anyone there guide me how to do this?

Comment: As far as I understand you need to set your app screens background.
You can do this by setting the background attribute for the parent view of your activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that BackGround or the Image view should always on top of other view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bu"/>

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:textSize="45sp"/>
<TextView android:text="Good_Day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:textSize="45sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: correct, but @Fed. i have 2 apps, main app and another app is about wallpaper app, what i want is to set the image on to my main app's background from the wallpaper app... for that what should i do??

Answer (score 1):

```
image extension not required....

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/hello"/>

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: correct, but @zap. i have 2 apps, main app and another app is about wallpaper app, what i want is to set the image on to my main app's background from the wallpaper app... for that what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented you need to do following -
Suppose you want to Set a background of your Apps Main Screen.
You can set the background of your parent view of your XML `layout` or you can have an `ImageView` as bottom layer  and rest view above this using the relative layout.
And now you can set the `ImageView` as you wish.

Comment: correct, but @Sanjeet. i have 2 apps, main app and another app is about wallpaper app, what i want is, to set the image on to my main app's background from the wallpaper app... for that what should i do??